# How to declare Datetime type column with DDMMYYYY format in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Below is my table structure:

```
DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE
(
[BranchID]          BIGINT          NULL,
[BranchName]        NVARCHAR(MAX)   NULL,
[Date]              DATETIME        NULL
)
```

My MSSQLSERVER is too crazy. It is saving the datetime in MMDDYYYY format, not knowing I required SELECT statement output in DDMMYYYY format. I am tired of using that **CONVERT()** and **CAST()** functions each and every time to in SELECT statement.

Is there any way to declare table column with my datetime format ( i.e. DDMMYYYY) so that I don't need to use **CONVERT()** or **CAST()** functions every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date Time gets stored in database with the default format based on selected default language for the user. However you can manipulate the format when fetching the date time.

Following is the way to fetch the data with different defined formats:
[All Formats for DateTime](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

But, if you still want to store the Date-Time of your own choice format then you have to create a column with `Varchar` DataType and later convert into date when fetching it (Not recommended)

`Convert(datetime, Expression, FormatStyle)`

For more information View the following answers:

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755849/changing-dateformat-on-a-sql-server-db-and-not-on-whole-server-to-dd-mm-yyyy)

[Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711719/change-default-dateformat-stored-in-a-database)

Comment: can you help me with where and how to set those DEFAULT FORMATS?

Comment: @Chetan for your information, look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755849/changing-dateformat-on-a-sql-server-db-and-not-on-whole-server-to-dd-mm-yyyy)
 and also this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711719/change-default-dateformat-stored-in-a-database)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. There is no formatting information at all associated with the field.

The value is not formatted by the database, it's returned only as a point in time. Formatting that value into it's textual representation is done by the applcation that is getting the data from the database.

So, there is nothing that you can do in the database to change how the date/datetime value is formatted, you have to change that where the data is displayed.

Comment: WHY? It is storing the value in same format **( i.e. MMDDYYYY)** every time. that means somewhere in database,  it is set in that way. So we just need to manipulate it with our format (DDMMYYYY)

Comment: Dates do not appear in any format in the table. SQL is based on abstraction. Plus In modern tiered architectures, display formatting is done in a presentation layers and never in the database.